# auto moderate comments

Tags: php, facebook, comments

I am using 'facebook comment plugin' for my website, but I am facing a problem which is all the comments have to be moderated before publishing, may I know how to make it auto-moderated?

my coding is as below:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789"/>  
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="987654321"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=987654321";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://abc.def.com/fb_comment.php" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470" data-colorscheme="light" data-mobile="false"></div>
</body>
```

Besides that, I also modified the comment plugin setting on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments .
1 - Moderation mode: Make every post public by default.
2 - Blacklisted words: No restrictions
3 - Other login providers: Don't allow users to post using other login providers.

The coding is working fine, but is anyone can teach me how to make it auto-moderated the comments? thanks.

Comment: "Admins can choose to make the default for new comments entered either “visible to everyone” or “has limited visibility” on the site (i.e., the comment is only visible to the commenter and their friends), to help mitigate irrelevant content." 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: Thanks daemonfire300, but where can I do this action? I can't find the option on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

Comment: Have you specified either your user id or an app id as moderator, by adding the necessary OG meta tag to the target page of your comments?